# BCa bootstrap for dependent categories?

Tags: categorical-data, bootstrap

We have used BCa bootstrap on estimation of forest proportion in different land categories. The sum of proportions have to be 1.

But using separately independent BCa method on every land category we have not got the sum 1. Question: how to perform BCa method on dependent samples (categories).